# how to program some "dynamic" graphic image like most seen in movie

Tags: video, dynamic

Usually you can see a lot of "dynamic" graphic images displaying on computer screen or part of robot or somewhere in movie. It's cool. I want to know how to archive that.
You can suggest some links like homepage or forums about this.
Or you can suggest some books about this.
In a word, you can give out any useful information about this.
And you can give out some "keyword". I will search them hard.
Maybe this is off-topic, but I think it should be relative with "program" (they can be drawn with code).
A simple example is "Conky", it can display relative graphic about computer information. And I want to draw graphic depend on any information I add in.

Answer (score 1):

I have used for small animation of charts with Processing (particulary JS impl ProcessingJS http://processingjs.org/). As Processing as ProcessingJS have rich set to draw charts and animate these.